# Can you version control pickle files with git?

Tags: python, git, pickle

Can you track the changes to pickle files with git like you can with csv? If you have a 1GB pickle file and you add 0.1GB to it each day and then push the changes to github, will it push the 0.1GB diff or the entire 1GB file? I need to choose a file type for data storage. Pickle will take up less space, but if it uses more bandwidth I'll use csv.

Comment: I think git tries to diff binary files but likely it will have to store the whole thing again. If the data fits in a CSV, then git would be able to diff it. But then, that makes it tabular data and other things like databases may be a good choice.

Comment: If a pickle file is binary data you might want to use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but for large data files you can try some specialized git-based solutions:

- [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.com)
- [DVC](https://dvc.org/)